# How to convert the time in different time zone ..how can i write standard code for all time zones be coverd

Tags: postgresql

Here the my code

```
select (case 
     when ptra.submitted_date is null then
                  DATE_PART('day', now()::timestamp - agent_accepted_date::timestamp)*24+
                  DATE_PART('hour', now()::timestamp - agent_accepted_date::timestamp) ||':'||
                  DATE_PART('min', now()::timestamp - agent_accepted_date::timestamp)
                         
     when  ptra.submitted_date is not null then 
           DATE_PART('day',submitted_date::timestamp - agent_accepted_date::timestamp)*24+
           DATE_PART('hour', submitted_date::timestamp - agent_accepted_date::timestamp) ||':'||
           DATE_PART('min', submitted_date::timestamp - agent_accepted_date::timestamp)
 end) as elapsed_id,
from project.pm_task_run_agent_assignments ptra
where task_run_agent_assignment_id = 5551
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you mean with "for all time zones covered"?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you can replace the three calls to `date_part` with a single expression using `to_char(now()::timestamp - agent_accepted_date::timestamp, 'dd hh24:mi')`